# Increase websocket connection timeout in apache pulsar

Tags: docker, configuration, apache-pulsar

Below is my configuration for running pulsar as a standalone version in docker-compose:

```
pulsar:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar:2.6.0
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 6650:6650
    environment:
      PULSAR_MEM: " -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1g"    
      PULSAR_PREFIX_webSocketSessionIdleTimeoutMillis: 36000000
    command: bash -c "bin/apply-config-from-env.py conf/standalone.conf && bin/pulsar standalone"
```

I am connecting pulsar from **browser-client side** as consumer. I am using JS websocket for connection.

Code for Client side :

```
new WebSocket(`ws://broker-service-url:8080/ws/v2/consumer/persistent/public/default/my-topic`)
```

And socket connection is successful.

Docker container is being created and after inspecting
`/pulsar/conf/standalone.conf` in docker container, i can see updated value in standalone.conf file also.

As per findings on internet, I found that we can override configuration by adding prefix PULSAR_PREFIX_ and running command bash -c "bin/apply-config-from-env.py conf/standalone.conf && bin/pulsar standalone".I want to increase timeout for websocket idle connection.By default it is 30 seconds and I want to increase it.

Still websocket connection is disconnected from client side after 30 seconds which is default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks not a problem with the server side. I try to test if on my laptop, here is the log from the standalone

```
2022-08-23T12:05:45,037+0800 [pulsar-web-57-12] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.RequestLog - 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2022:12:05:44 +0800] "GET /ws/v2/consumer/persistent/public/default/my-topic/my-sub HTTP/1.1" 101 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 538
2022-08-23T12:05:45,041+0800 [pulsar-web-57-12] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.websocket.AbstractWebSocketHandler - [/127.0.0.1:62398] New WebSocket session on topic persistent://public/default/my-topic
2022-08-23T12:10:45,052+0800 [Connector-Scheduler-76fa3dd8-1] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.websocket.AbstractWebSocketHandler - [/127.0.0.1:62398] WebSocket error on topic persistent://public/default/my-topic : java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 300002/300000 ms
2022-08-23T12:10:45,054+0800 [pulsar-io-29-1] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.ServerCnx - [/127.0.0.1:62399] Closing consumer: consumerId=0
2022-08-23T12:10:45,055+0800 [pulsar-io-29-1] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.AbstractDispatcherSingleActiveConsumer - Removing consumer Consumer{subscription=PersistentSubscription{topic=persistent://public/default/my-topic, name=my-sub}, consumerId=0, consumerName=8092a, address=/127.0.0.1:62399}
2022-08-23T12:10:45,055+0800 [pulsar-io-29-1] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.broker.service.ServerCnx - [/127.0.0.1:62399] Closed consumer, consumerId=0
2022-08-23T12:10:45,055+0800 [pulsar-client-io-87-2] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConsumerImpl - [persistent://public/default/my-topic] [my-sub] Closed consumer
2022-08-23T12:10:45,057+0800 [Connector-Scheduler-76fa3dd8-1] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.websocket.AbstractWebSocketHandler - [/127.0.0.1:62398] Closed WebSocket session on topic persistent://public/default/my-topic. status: 1001 - reason: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 300002/300000 ms
```

The session closed as expected (5min by default) not 30s
But I'm not using the JS WebSocket Client.

It looks like should be an issue with the JS WebSocket Client.

BTW, the URL you provided `ws://broker-service-url:8080/ws/v2/consumer/persistent/public/default/my-topic` is not correct which missed the subscription name.

After change to `ws://url:8080/ws/v2/consumer/persistent/public/default/my-topic/my-sub`, I'm able to connect to the standalone.

Comment: Can you tell me which websocket client did you use?

Comment: I'm just using this tool http://www.websocket-test.com/

Comment: I see got it. Thanks let me check and will get back to you.

Comment: Hi @Penghui Li. thanks for your input. Yes i tried and it was from browser side.Browser was closing idle socket connection if it is not receiving data.So ideally for now I started to send ping from producer to this particular consumer.Is there any inbuilt ping-pong system from pulsar? Thanks for support.

Comment: Yes, but it only available for pulsar protocol 
https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/pulsar-common/src/main/proto/PulsarApi.proto#L670-L676

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with your docker compose file. I see the config file is updated

```
root@5aabba6324bc:/pulsar# more conf/standalone.conf | grep webSocketSessionIdleTimeoutMillis
webSocketSessionIdleTimeoutMillis=36000000
```

And it also can be found in the log

```
Attaching to downloads_pulsar_1
pulsar_1  | [conf/standalone.conf] Applying config webSocketSessionIdleTimeoutMillis = 36000000
pulsar_1  | [conf/standalone.conf] Updating config webSocketSessionIdleTimeoutMillis = 36000000
pulsar_1  | [AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.2 built on Wednesday Oct 24, 2018 at 15:43:33 GMT
pulsar_1  | [AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
pulsar_1  | [AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info using configuration file:/pulsar/lib/org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-zookeeper-utils-2.6.0.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
pulsar_1  | [AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info using configuration file:/pulsar/lib/org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-zookeeper-2.6.0.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
pulsar_1  | [AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect org.apache.pulsar.broker.zookeeper.aspectj.ClientCnxnAspect
pulsar_1  | [AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect org.apache.pulsar.zookeeper.FinalRequestProcessorAspect
```

Looks like it's not the issue of the update config file script.
But maybe an issue with the WebSocket implementation.

Have you tried a new version such as 2.9.3 or 2.10.1? I'm not sure
if the issue has been fixed or not. If you can also see the issue
on a new version. It's better to raise up a Github issue [here](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues).

Comment: Thanks for reply.I will try with version that you specified and let you know.

Comment: I have tried with 2.9.3 version but still no luck.Same issue.And with 2.10.1, I am getting below error:

```conf/standalone.conf] Applying config webSocketSessionIdleTimeoutMillis = 36000000
[conf/standalone.conf] Updating config webSocketSessionIdleTimeoutMillis = 36000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/apply-config-from-env.py", line 104, in <module>
    f = open(conf_filename, 'w')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'conf/standalone.conf```

do you think i can go ahead with issue reporting in github?

Comment: For the error log `Permission denied`, it should be related to the non-root image change in 2.10.0. https://github.com/apache/pulsar-helm-chart#upgrading-to-2100-and-above Please check here to get more details about upgrading to 2.10.x